# What to do when android doesn't detect my .css and .js files when I run index.html?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, miui

I wrote a .html file that uses css(style.css) and javascript(app.js).
When I **transferred the folder containing the index.html,style.css and app.js over to my android internal memory,the browser runs the html file but my .css and .js files are not detected.**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <head>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
            </head>
            <body>
             ....
            </body>
            <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have tried using "/style.css" and "./style.css".
But none of them are helping in detecting the files.

Inline styles in the index.html file work fine and show up in my browser.

***Using Chrome on Android 8.1.0 (MIUI 10.1|Stable)***

Answer (score 0):

You can load your files somewhere in your device like this :

- file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDirectory/index.html
- file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDirectory/style.css
- file:///storage/emulated/0/MyDirectory/app.js

And then try to address thoes in `src` and `href`.

---

For testing purposes you can also use applications that let you run local servers on your device, like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.apache

Comment: Tanks for answering ,however, it still doesn't help detect the files. Apparently, Chrome doesn't have the permission to read files .When I type in file:///storage in address bar, it shows me ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.shira.html.viewer 
Using that app , the HTML file was able to run perfectly.